# natbib all references zero

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

I am unable to provide a minimal working example for this.

I am including two chapters in my document like this:

```
\input{chapters/chapter1/tex/main}
\input{chapters/chapter2/tex/main}
```

When both are included, then all my references are zero, whereas everything works fine, if I comment out either line. Has anyone experience this before? What might be causing it? I've looked for duplicate `\label`, but found none.

I am using the natbib package:

```
%https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#biblatex
\usepackage[natbib,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,uniquelist=false,backend=biber,
style=numeric,
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
refsection=chapter,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references_modified.bib}
```

Comment: I got rid of `refsection=chapter` and that seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: `refsection=chapter` should cause no such problem. It might not give you the output you expect, but it should work. If you have all zeroes in your document, you should try to delete the auxiliary files and compile again.

Comment: @moewe Just deleting the auxiliary files and recompiling did not solve the problem.

Comment: That was just a guess. But your question does not give enough details to investigate more.

Comment: @moewe That's true. It's unfortunately impossible to create a mwe. But I seem to have found a solution.

Comment: The thing is that your solution is a really weird one. The option should not cause the problem you describe.

Comment: @moewe And it doesn't, because now I have the same problem again. I will investigate and report back with the permanent solution. It's only when I combine certain chapters that the problem occurs.

Comment: If at all possible an MWE would of course enable us to give a few suggestions and hints.

Comment: @moewe I'm currently using `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` to identify the problematic `subsection`. I have identifed the `chapter` and the `section` causing the problem. I'll hopefully have a solution soon. Once I've solved the problem I will create a MWE with and without the problematic part.

Comment: Any news here? Could you isolate the problem?

Comment: @moewe I've been in bed with the flu. I will look at it this week. Sorry about that.

Comment: @moewe Problem finally solved. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this! My file `references.bib` contained a line like this:

```
Author = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and ,},
```

I removed the last `and ,`:

```
Author = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2},
```

And now it works. The `references.bib` file was corrupt, but I never got a warning. Is there a piece of code out there dedicated to detecting errors like these?

Comment: It's not quite right to say you never got any warning. Biber crashes with `FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash: Inappropriate I/O control operation` But I have to admit that message is not particularly enlightening. Since the error appears in a low-level parsing stage I guess not a lot can be done to make the message more informative. But you can always ask: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues